# Table on the same page as Chapter Title

Tags: tables, formatting, geometry

I am writing my thesis and being new to latex, I am having problem placing my table in the same page as the chapter title page. One of my appendix only contains tables with no text, but the table appears on the next page from the page containing the tile page even though there's enough space above and below the table. Hope the attached figure helps better understand the problem.
[image: ![enter image description here]

My code looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=25mm, right=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, tabularx, mathtools, array, multirow, booktabs, pdflscape}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{appendices}
%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}%---------supress sectioning in TOC
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{10}\bfseries\raggedright}{\chaptertitlename{} \thechapter:}{0.3em}{\fontsize{14}{10}}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-15pt}{10pt}
\chapter{Rock Mass Parameter selection guidelines}
%
\begin{table}
\caption{Field estimate of Uniaxial Compressive Strength (UCS).}
\footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.4\hsize \centering\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize \raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize \centering\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\hsize=0.4\hsize \centering\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
    >{ \raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Grade*}&    \textbf{Term}&  \textbf{Uniaxial Comp. Strength (MPa)}& \textbf{Point Load Index (MPa)}&    \textbf{Field estimate of strength}&    \textbf{Examples}\\
    \midrule
    R6& Extremely Strong&   $>$250& $>$10&  Specimen can only be chipped with a geological hammer&  Fresh basalt, chert,diabase, gneiss, granite, quartzite\\
    \addlinespace
    R5& Very Strong&    100--250&   4--10&  Specimen requires many blows of a geological hammer to fracture it& Amphiobolite, sandstone, basalt, gabbro, gneiss, granodiorite, limestone, marble, rhyolite, tuff\\
    \addlinespace
    R4& Strong& 50--100&    2--4&   Specimen requires more than one blow of a geological hammer to fracture it& Limestone, marble, phyllite, sandstone, schist, shale\\
    \addlinespace
    R3& Medium Strong&  25--50& 1--2&   Cannot be scraped or peeled with a pocket knife, specimen can be fractured with a single blow from a geological hammer& Claystone, coal, concrete, schist, shale, siltstone\\
    \addlinespace
    R2& Weak&   5--25&  **& Can be peeled with a pocket knife with difficulty, shallow indentation made by firm blow with a point of geological hammer&  Chalk, rocksalt, potash\\
    \addlinespace
    R1& Very Weak&  1--5&   **& Crumble under firm blows with point of a geological hammer, can be peeled by a pocket knife&    Highly weathered or altered rock\\
    \addlinespace
    R0& Extremely Weak& 0.21--1&    **& Indented by thumbnail&  Stiff fault gouge\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    * Grade according to Brown (1981)\\
    ** Point load tests on rocks with a UCS below 25 MPa are likely to yield highly ambiguous results.
    \label{CT1}
\end{table}
%
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

P.S. I might have missed some packages while creating this MWE since there are a lot in my original document to be placed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, LaTeX limits the amount of a regular text page that can be dedicated to floats (such as `table`) so your table was pushed to a float page. You will need to manually specify “here” placement for the table (and, if necessary ensure that it does in fact fit in the available space on the page), by adding `[h!]` to the `\begin{table}` command.

Incidentally, your MWE was missing `\usepackage{titlesec}`.