# Fill width table on same page as \maketitle for twocolumn article

Tags: tables, titles, two-column

Good morning/day/evening/night!

I'm in a situation where I need to fit a full width (i.e. paper wide) table into a single page multicolumn document and there seems to be some underlying conflict with the `table*` environment and the `\maketitle` command.

What I would like is:

- Primarily help with getting the table onto the first page
- Secondly getting some understanding on why there is a problem in the first place

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twocolumn
    ]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{test}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{table*}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
      col 1 & col 2\\
      val 1 & val 2\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

This results in a two page pdf where the table is on the second page, and I need it on the first page. To avoid posting something that has already been solved somewhere on StackExchange I looked around a bit and have found a couple of related posts, a few are these

- [Table on the same page as Chapter Title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595512/table-on-the-same-page-as-chapter-title)
- [\twocolumn[{\begin{@twocolumnfalse} explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57584/twocolumn-begintwocolumnfalse-explained)
- [title and abstract and table of contents in the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544900/title-and-abstract-and-table-of-contents-in-the-same-page)
- [Forcing a full-width table to be on the same page as it is mentioned in two-column document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560273/forcing-a-full-width-table-to-be-on-the-same-page-as-it-is-mentioned-in-two-colu)
- [Page-wide table in two-column mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode)

and I've tried the proposed solutions to no avail. The last in the list states that for `table*` environments only `t` (top of page) and `p` (end of document) are allowed and my problem might have something to do with this.

So hopefully someone here can provide a solution, and if this is not even possible to do that would also be good to know.

In either case, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: This answer is a hack, and requires manual effort, but it should work: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Comment: This seems to fill all my requirements; it's a bit hacky but it works! Thank you for the answer!